# angularjs directive displays json during page load

Tags: json, angularjs, directive

I'm building my first AngularJS dynamic form, built based on information received from a JSON file using AngularJS directive.

Everything works, my issue is that the JSON code is getting displayed while the page is loaded - once the page is loaded the JSON code disappears.

Am I doing something wrong?

Check http://plnkr.co/edit/v4jOwuF6jmZfORlNbvIB?p=preview to see the behavior, click on "Stop"/"Start" multiple times to see the behavior.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.2" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.2/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="ViewCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="page in form.form_pages">
      <div ng-repeat="field in page.page_fields" class="form-group">
        <field-directive field="field" ng-form="subForm"></field-directive>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

js code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp',[])
    .controller('ViewCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        var jsonStr='{"form_id":"1","form_name":"My Test Form","form_pages":{"1":{"page_id":1,"page_title":"My First Tab","page_hide":false,"page_fields":{"1":{"field_id":1,"field_title":"First Name","field_type":"textfield","field_value":"","field_required":true,"field_disabled":false},"2":{"field_id":2,"field_title":"Last Name","field_type":"textfield","field_value":"","field_required":true,"field_disabled":false},"3":{"field_id":3,"field_title":"Gender","field_type":"textfield","field_value":"0","field_required":true,"field_disabled":false},"4":{"field_id":4,"field_title":"Email Address","field_type":"textfield","field_value":"","field_required":true,"field_disabled":false},"5":{"field_id":5,"field_title":"Password","field_type":"textfield","field_value":"","field_required":true,"field_disabled":false},"6":{"field_id":6,"field_title":"Birth Date","field_type":"textfield","field_value":"1981-01-10T06:00:00.000Z","field_required":true,"field_disabled":false},"7":{"field_id":7,"field_title":"Your browser","field_type":"textfield","field_value":"2","field_required":false,"field_disabled":false},"8":{"field_id":8,"field_title":"Additional Comments","field_type":"textarea","field_value":"","field_required":true,"field_disabled":false},"9":{"field_id":9,"field_title":"I accept the terms and conditions.","field_type":"textfield","field_value":"0","field_required":true,"field_disabled":false}}}}}';

        $scope.form = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

    }])

    .directive('fieldDirective',function($http, $compile) {

      var linker = function(scope, element) {
        // GET template content from path
        var templateUrl = "textfield.html";
        $http.get(templateUrl).success(function(data) {
            element.html(data);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        });
      }

      return {
        template: '<div>{{field}}</div>',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            field: '='
        },
        link: linker
    };
    })
```

textfield.html - the html template:

```
<div class="row" ng-form="subForm" ng-class="{'has-success': subForm[field.field_id].$invalid}">
    <div class="col-sm-5">{{field.field_title}}:</div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="text"
            placeholder="{{field.field_title}}"
            ng-model="field.field_value" 
            value="{{field.field_value}}" 
            ng-required="field.field_required"
            ng-disabled="field.field_disabled"
            class="form-control"
            id = "{{field.field_id}}"
            name = "{{field.field_id}}" >
        <div ng-show="subForm[field.field_id].$touched && subForm[field.field_id].$error && subForm[field.field_id].$invalid">Field '{{field.field_title}}'
            <span ng-show="subForm[field.field_id].$error.required"> is required.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the *relevant* parts of the code in the question itself - don't rely on external links (although having a link to plunker - as an additional reference - is always good). This is a good guide on the best way to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Cannot fully eleborate on why, think it's cycles of addinbg things to the dom, having angular apply it's binding etc. but you can prevent the issue by changing way you link (template: '<div data-ng-model="field"></div>',)

Comment: Thanks @MarvinSmit this was the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/YC9p0UluhHyEgAjA4D8R?p=preview

Basically instead of adding the loaded template into the element then compiling it in place I just compile the string then insert the compiled element directly

```
        element.append($compile(data)(scope));
```

Seems you can still see a delay but this might be the async loading of the template causing that, would need to debug in the network panel and do some profiling or logging to see exactly what's going on.

**Edit**
Made a fork of the plnkr to show one with the template inlined so there's no delay fetching it with $http http://plnkr.co/edit/Tnc3VOeI8cELDJDHYPTO?p=preview instead just grabbing it synchronously from the template cache and using ng-template in a script block to have it loaded in advance.

Comment: Thanks @shaunhusain you got me on the right track. It turns out all I had to do was change: `template: '<div>{{field}}</div>',` to `template: '<div></div>',`